# discord.py - why does client.run claim I'm not using a string, or getting a 401?

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I'm creating a cheap DND dice rolling bot for Discord. I intend for slash commands like `/d20s 4 2` to give 4 rolls of a 20-sided die with a modifier of +2. Since the slash commands are public and the bot runs on one machine, I figured that would keep us all honest while playing remotely.

```
 1  # bot.py
 2
 3  import os
 4
 5  import discord
 6  import dotenv
 7
 8  ints = discord.Intents.default()
 9
10  dotenv.load_dotenv()
11  TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
12
13  client = discord.Client(intents=ints)
14
15  @client.event
16  async def on_ready():
17      print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
18
19  client.run(TOKEN)
```

The file sourced looks like this:

```
 1  DISCORD_TOKEN=123456789123456789
```

The error I'm getting back is:

```
INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 19, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 849, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 777, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 609, in login
    raise TypeError(f'expected token to be a str, received {token.__class__.__name__} instead')
TypeError: expected token to be a str, received NoneType instead
```

I looked it up, and the command used *does* return a str. What am I doing wrong? On a similar question, someone said they forgot to export the variable. So, I sourced the file and double-checked that it was in the environment:

```
> source token.txt
> echo $DISCORD_TOKEN
123456789123456789
```

I tried export DISCORD_TOKEN=123456789123456789 but now it says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 19, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 849, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 777, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 612, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "/home/john/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 807, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

Edit - I moved the token string into the main bot.py file (not what I'd like!) and it worked, at least, it logged on. Can you tell me what I was doing wrong? I don't want the token there because the bot's open source, I used .gitignore to prevent uploading of the token but that won't work with bot.py.

Comment: Okay, so the error is a 401 and my token was wrong. I corrected the token and I'm still getting a 401, "improper token has been passed."

Comment: I may have solved this, I have to backtrack to figure out what I did. I'm still not getting working slash commands but I am getting it to log in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it's supposed to work, but the way I got it to work is I put the token in a python file and imported it. Make sure the token file, whatever you call it, doesn't go public.